# anova_test not returning Mauchly's for three way within subject ANOVA

Tags: anova, rstatix

I am using a data set called sleep (found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZnsWtzbPpUBQN9qr-KZCnyX-0CYJHL5/view) to run a three way within subject ANOVA comparing Performance based on Stimulation, Deprivation, and Time. I have successfully done this before using anova_test from rstatix. I want to look at the sphericity output but it doesn't appear in the output. I have got it to come up with other three way within subject datasets, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
anova_test(data = sleep, dv = Performance, wid = Subject, within = c(Stimulation, Deprivation, Time))
```

I also tried to save it to an object and use get_anova_table, but that didn't look any different.

```
sleep_aov <- anova_test(data = sleep, dv = Performance, wid = Subject, within = c(Stimulation, Deprivation, Time))
get_anova_table(sleep_aov, correction = "GG")
```

This is an ideal dataset I pulled from the internet, so I'm starting to think the data had a W of 1 (perfect sphericity) and so rstatix is skipping this output. Is this something anova_test does?

Here also is my code using a dataset that does return Mauchly's:

```
weight_loss_long <- pivot_longer(data = weightloss, cols = c(t1, t2, t3), names_to = "time", values_to = "loss")
weight_loss_long$time <- factor(weight_loss_long$time)
anova_test(data = weight_loss_long, dv = loss, wid = id, within = c(diet, exercises, time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert at all, but it might be because your factors have only two levels.

From anova_summary() help:

"Value
return an object of class anova_test a data frame containing the ANOVA table for independent measures ANOVA. However, for repeated/mixed measures ANOVA, it is a list containing the following components are returned:

ANOVA: a data frame containing ANOVA results

Mauchly's Test for Sphericity: If any within-Ss variables with more than 2 levels are present, a data frame containing the results of Mauchly's test for Sphericity. Only reported for effects that have more than 2 levels because sphericity necessarily holds for effects with only 2 levels.

Sphericity Corrections: If any within-Ss variables are present, a data frame containing the Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt epsilon values, and corresponding corrected p-values. "